# How Can I Stop a New Window Inheriing the Menu of the Main Window

Tags: java, swing

I have a main class which loads my application window when the program starts, as shown in following code:

```
public class SwendaEye{

    public static void main(String[]args){  
    FrameandComp frame = new FrameandComp();
    JFrame win;

    win = frame.mainFrame();
    /*========================================================================*/
    JMenuBar bar;
    bar = new JMenuBar();
    win.setJMenuBar(bar); 

    JMenu swenda = new JMenu("SWENDAEYE");// adding Swenda menu to the bar.
    bar.add(swenda);

                 JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
                 swenda.add(open);
                 JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
                 swenda.add(exit);

    JMenu tools = new JMenu("Tools");// adding Tools menu to the bar.
    bar.add(tools);
                 JMenuItem convertIP = new JMenuItem("Convert IP Address");
                 tools.add(convertIP);
                 JMenuItem convertDomain = new JMenuItem("Convert Domain Name");
                 tools.add(convertDomain);
                 Domain dom = new Domain();

                 dom.iniTheEvent(convertDomain);
                 convertDomain.addActionListener(dom);

       JMenu view = new JMenu("View"); // adding Swenda menu to the bar.
       bar.add(view);
                 JMenuItem webDetail = new JMenuItem("Website header");
                 view.add(webDetail);
                 JMenuItem report = new JMenuItem("Report");
                 view.add(report);

       win.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I click on the Domain converter for example, I should be able to trigger a new window that is set in the `Domain` class. In my case the window does open, but  the "domain Converter" window contains a  `Menu` that was defined in the `Main` class when  it should only have a button and a text field. As you can see, I have not implemented or initiated a `Menu` or `MenuItem` anywhere in the `Domain` class.

```
public class Domain implements ActionListener{

    FrameandComp frame = new FrameandComp();
    JFrame domFrame;
    String DomainTitle= "Domain Converter";
    TextField text = new TextField(20);
    JButton bot = new JButton("Convert");
    JMenuItem men;
    public Domain(){        
    }

    public void createFrame(){


        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(); // Create a layout manager
        domFrame =frame.setFrame(400,200,DomainTitle,JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        Container content = domFrame.getContentPane(); // Get the content pane
        content.setLayout(flow);
        content.add(text);
        content.add(bot);
        domFrame.add(content);
        domFrame.setVisible(true);

    }


    public JMenuItem iniTheEvent(JMenuItem menuIt){
        return men = menuIt;
    }



     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

               if(event.getSource() == men ){
                   this.createFrame();
               }

        }


}
```

I would like to be able to click on the Domain converter `MenuItem` and be able to open a new window without inheriting any of the menu functionality from the main window.

Can someone tell me what have I done wrong in my application that could cause my new window to inherit the menu of the main window?

Your support will be highly appreciated.

The `FrameandComp` class is used to initialize all of the `JFrames`:

```
public class FrameandComp {
    static JFrame awindow = new JFrame();

        public FrameandComp(){}




        public  JFrame setFrame(int width, int height, String title, int exitRule){

            Toolkit thekit = awindow.getToolkit();
            Dimension wndsize =  thekit.getScreenSize();
            awindow.setBounds(wndsize.width/4,wndsize.height/4,width, height);
            awindow.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            awindow.setTitle(title);
            awindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(exitRule);
            return awindow;

        }


        public JFrame mainFrame(){

            Toolkit thekit = awindow.getToolkit();
            Dimension wndsize =  thekit.getScreenSize();
            awindow.setBounds(wndsize.width/4,wndsize.height/4,
            ((2 *wndsize.width)/2), ((2 *wndsize.height)/2));
            awindow.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            awindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            awindow.setTitle("SWENDAEYE");
            return awindow;

        }


}
```

Comment: what is `FrameandComp`?

Comment: is the class that i use to intiate all Jframes.

Comment: please for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable, compilable

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a simple input dialog have a look at [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) (or [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/InputPopUps.htm) for some examples)

Comment: No i want to have my custome window so that i can display message if there is any wrong input.

Comment: @salimalmughairi And how is that different from want JOptionPane does?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Domain` class, remove this line -

```
FrameandComp frame = new FrameandComp();
```

and in the `createFrame()` method initialize the domFrame object as a new JFrame -

```
domFrame = new JFrame(DomainTitle);
domFrame.setSize(400,200);
```

instead of -

```
domFrame =frame.setFrame(400,200,DomainTitle,JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

You are adding elements to the frame object instead of creating a new JFrame (window) which you mentioned.

I would recommend if you just want take input from user try

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)
```

Hope that helps you..

Answer (score 0):

In your `FrameandComp` class, you create a single instance of `awindow` and use it for both the `mainframe` and `setFrame` methods.

Instead, try creating a new frame in each of these methods and return that, so that, every time you call one of these methods, you get a new frame.